# Is there a simple rule defining the sequence $\frac 1 2, 1, -\frac 1 2, -1, \frac 1 4, \frac 1 2, \dots$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm revisiting one of my old topology texts: "Introduction to Metric and Topological Spaces" by W.A. Sutherland, 1975 (the 1981 reprint with corrections), Oxford Science Publications.

One of the example illustrating how a sequence can be defined by a rule goes:

"Examples 1.2.1. (c) $\frac 1 2, 1, -\frac 1 2, -1, \frac 1 4, \frac 1 2, \dots,$

"In these examples, there is a simple formula for $s_n$ in terms of $n$, which the reader will spot."

No, I can't see an "obvious" rule to define this sequence.

In the course lecture notes there was a comment to the effect that the tutorial team themselves had not been able to spot the rule either.

It would of course possible to define any arbitrary rule, but it would be pretty contrived, and there would be no guarantee that it would generate the "correct" continuation.

I understand that Sutherland has more recently run to a second edition (2009) but I have not laid hands on it to check whether this has been amended.

But the immediate question is: can anyone identify what the "simple formula" may actually be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it is $$...,\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}, -\frac{1}{2^n}, -\frac{1}{2^{n-1}},... , $$ $n=1,2,...$.

Comment: This is the sort of "contrived rule" I was talking about. It does the job, it matches the numbers given (although a person does need to do some work on it to make it into an actual mapping from $\mathbb N$ to the set of terms), but there's no "intuitive" feel that it may or may not be the "right" sequence.

Comment: This is just the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Yes I get that, a similar technique came to mine, but I got bogged down on the aspect of implementing it as a mapping.

Comment: Just map $4n+1$ to $\frac{1}{2^n}$, $4n+2$ to $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$, and so on, $n=1,2,...$

Comment: "Just". A teacher's best friend.

Comment: First, regarding "contrived rules", "intuitive" feel, and "right" sequence, when someone asserts that a six term sequence has some kind of "simple" formula, anything one writes down is liable to be "contrived", or to violate "intuition" or "rightness".

Comment: Second, I'm not sure what "implementing as a mapping" even means, but if it means writing down a formula, you can "just" write down a four part formula $$x_{4n+i} = \begin{cases} 2^{-1-n} & i=1 \\ 2^{-n} & i=2 \\ -2^{-1-n} & i=3 \\ -2^{-n} & i=4 \end{cases} \qquad\qquad\text{for all $n \ge 0$, $i=0,1,2,3$}$$ I don't see how you are going to escape the need for some kind of multi-part formula, either as in this answer or the other one, where the multi-part nature of the other answer is hidden in the use of the ceiling function $\lceil x \rceil$ and the modulus function.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite simple, but one way to write it.

There is a group of 4, so it has to do something with $\frac{n}{4}$.
My approach is to write up what we want first for the exponent of 2, then for the exponent of -1, that creates the negativ terms.

Expected exponent of 2:
$1 \rightarrow 1$
$2 \rightarrow 0$
$3 \rightarrow 1$
$4 \rightarrow 0$
$5 \rightarrow 2$
$6 \rightarrow 1$
$7 \rightarrow 2$
$8 \rightarrow 1$
...
Now if we try to use $\left\lceil\frac{n}{4}\right\rceil$, we get
$1 \rightarrow 1$
$2 \rightarrow 1$
$3 \rightarrow 1$
$4 \rightarrow 1$
$5 \rightarrow 2$
$6 \rightarrow 2$
$7 \rightarrow 2$
$8 \rightarrow 2$
...
This needs to be adjusted by subtracting 1 from every second term. This can be done by using $n - 1$ mod $2$, which is
$1 \rightarrow 0$
$2 \rightarrow 1$
$3 \rightarrow 0$
$4 \rightarrow 1$
$5 \rightarrow 0$
$6 \rightarrow 1$
$7 \rightarrow 0$
$8 \rightarrow 1$
...
So the formula for the exponent of 2 is $\left\lceil\frac{n}{4}\right\rceil - (n - 1$ mod $2)$.

Expected exponent of -1:
$1 \rightarrow even$
$2 \rightarrow even$
$3 \rightarrow odd$
$4 \rightarrow odd$
$5 \rightarrow even$
$6 \rightarrow even$
$7 \rightarrow odd$
$8 \rightarrow odd$
...
Now if we try to use $\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil$, we get
$1 \rightarrow odd$
$2 \rightarrow odd$
$3 \rightarrow even$
$4 \rightarrow even$
$5 \rightarrow odd$
$6 \rightarrow odd$
$7 \rightarrow even$
$8 \rightarrow even$
...
So the formula for the exponent of -1 is $\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil - 1$.

Comment: As you say, not quite simple, but it does the job. It gets an upvote, but I'm reserving the "accepted answer" for whoever can report back on what appears in the 2009 edition, which I don't want to have to get myself because I already have the 1st edition.

Comment: @PrimeMover Ok, I don't have that text, so I don't know if that has anything in common with my approach.

Comment: The point is that the 1st edition just presented the sequence with the comment about how "there is a simple formula ... which the reader will spot." This makes me wonder whether, because of possible feedback, that in the 2nd edition: he will have a) "corrected" this sequence to whatever the "obvious" sequence was he was thinking of, b) explained what the rule was, or c) scrapped that sequence as unhelpful and unenlightening. I really want to understand what he was getting at, but Sutherland has died so I can't ask him directly.